# Alert - this app will be impacted by a policy change . READ_CALL_LOG not in Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

I have Xamarin.Forms project and product is on Google Play. Google Play Console gives the 


Alert  this app will be impacted by a policy change
This app will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy governing the use of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions. Apps that are not compliant may be removed from Google Play on Jan 9th, 2019.


In e-mail Google says READ_CALL_LOG effects my application but there is no READ_CALL_LOG in my manifest. What can cause this situation?

Comment: It could be a false positive (contact Play support)...Are you sure that your app does nothing with the call log? Are you including any 3rd-party libraries that are? (apps using 3rd-party libraries where caught skimming logs... even Facebook Ads was doing it)    Are you directly accessing any system sqlite DBs? (as that is not allowed) Or via a content provider? Etc... Also double check the "final" manifest (not the one in your solution, but the one generated/merged in your release/obj dir) to ensure that some lib is not altering the manifest.

Comment: Just saw that your title says "READ_CALL_LOG not in Manifest" Is the "NOT" actually stated by Google? If so, they have scanned your app code and it is accessing the call log.... If you are not doing it, then a 3rd-party lib might be...

Comment: I checked final version of the AndroidManifest from release\obj but there is no READ_CALL_LOG.

Comment: Few weeks ago, I got a warning about violating metadata policy and one of my app was removed from Playstore. I contacted Google Play Support Team and asked about it and also told that I have done nothing against the metadata policy. Later, I was able to resubmit the app from console and republished it successfully. 
Also, I'm getting the same alert about the permission periodically but there are no READ_CALL_LOG permissions or anything like that in the manifest file. Since, it's already 11 January and my app is still there in Playstore, this alert also seems like a glitch from Google to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `READ_CALL_LOG` permission to your manifest if your app, or one of the libraries you are using, reads the call log.

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml file inside the `<manifest>` element, but outside the `<activity>` element. e.g.:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

The other option is to find what in your app or a library it uses is trying to access the call log and remove that code and/or library.